# inlineEdit rows of a grid on Magento 2 not working

Tags: magento, inline-editing

I need some columns of my grid to be clickable and editable, im doing what magento tutorials say but its not working.

I've tried almost everything, and rows are not clickable and the editor does not appear.

Thanks for the help.

Here is my listing.xml; the columns part.

```
    <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="sellermania/market/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sellermania_market_listing.sellermania_market_listing.sellermania_market_listing.spinner_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sellermania_market_listing.sellermania_market_listing.sellermania_market_listing_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>

</listing>
```